# how to make git find my files in the library folder, not ignored by gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is my .gitignore file:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
.metadata
local.properties
.classpath
.loadpath
.settings

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
/project.properties
/proguard-project.txt
.settings
/lint.xml
```

Result of git status:

## On branch master

nothing to commit, working directory clean

After git add library same result... And a `ls -al library/` show me my files!

Comment: Based on the plethora of information you've provided, I'd suggest you run `git add` against the files you'd like to track.

Comment: "git add libraries; git status" or give us more information including the "git status" before and after your attempt to git something.

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: @SébastienDawans in title, English is not my native language, but it is not a reason to vote negatively ...If you do not understand a few things you can always ask me. If it's in my abilities, I will speak better

Comment: don't expect to get any help, your question is too unclear. When you improve it i will remove the -1, of course. By the way I didn't mention anything about the language.

Comment: maybe, but you didn't say also what's it unclear for you...If there was a question already asked  or anything like that, but there wasn't....It's nothing, in all community there are black sheeps ;)

Comment: `git add -f <files>` to add ignored files for tracking.

Comment: @kan this add files ignored yes, but not the files in my folder library :'(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted the file. git, and make a new git init followed by git remote add origin https://github.com/ .... git add. && gitignore git add. && Git commit-a-m "go" && git push and it worked...